# Encode-DecodeAdventure

Tags: java, javascript, decode, encode

I tried to encode special characters in javascript using `encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent()` functions and decode them using the `java.net.URLDecoder.decode()` method and this worked like a charm in firefox. but it doesn't seem to be working in Internet explorer. Is there any alternative code where the same code would work on both browsers?

Example:

when I pass `$%^&` as the value, after encoding, it becomes `%24%25%5E%26`. After decoding using java.net.URLDecoder.decode() method, it becomes `$%%5E&`

this is the actual value-

```
var str = "$%^&";
var valueJS = encodeURI(str);
var valueJS = encodeURIComponent(valueJS); // to encode even those chars in valueJS that were not encoded by encodeURI()
```

this is the encoded value-

```
String value = "%2524%2525%255E%2526";
while(value.matches(".*%25[A-Za-z0-9]*")) {
     value = value.replace("%25", "%"); // manually trying to achieve %24%25%5E%26
}
value = java.net.URLDecoder(value, "UTF-8");

// I was expecting the decoded value to be $%^&, but it turns out to be $%%5E&
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What problems or error messages are you seeing?

Comment: I'm unable to decode using the above mentioned java API

Comment: You said that, but what *exactly* isn't working? What problems or error messages are you seeing? What happens?

Comment: There are no error messages as such. But my decoded values are supposed to be used for certain execution purpose, if my encoded values are not properly decoded, the execution will not successfully happen. My point is - the decode() method is not decoding at all.

Comment: Can you show an example value before and after the decoding and some code?

Comment: Ok i'll update the question in a while.

Comment: @Pekka웃 i've added an example

Comment: This is getting closer to a good question!  Please add the actual line of Java code that's doing the decoding.  Which `URLDecoder.decode()` method are you calling?  Is it the deprecated one?

Comment: i'll update my question in a while

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot: I've added the code. Hope this makes my question clearer.

Comment: Improving.  I think the code you added is not the code you're running, though.  For example, if you run the Java code you posted, you *do* get the value you're expecting.  But the JavaScript code you posted will not produce that string.  You're double-encoding and so you should get `%24%2525%255E%26` as your final encoded string.

Comment: Ya... I traced the code. I found that the final encoded value is `%2524%252525%255E%2526`. I'm making certain checks before decoding. will update the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. Added 2 `<meta>` tags

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

and used javascript `escape()` instead of `encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent()`